# SubSonic, SQL Server and MySQL problems table names [ ClienteEndereco Clienteendereco ]

Tags: mysql, sql-server, subsonic

I was making tests with SubSonic with SQL Server and everything was fine.

I decided to install MySQL and made the same tests, but now I have a little problem

My table name is ClienteEndereco in SQL Server but when i make change in my web.config to work with MYSQL and recompile the program the table name comes Clienteendereco

```
SQL Server = Cliente**E**ndereco
MySql      = Cliente**e**ndereco
```

I tried to use `regexIgnoreCase="true"` but nothing happens.

Can anyone help to solve that?  How to make subsonic "ignores case" in SQL Server and MySql?

Thank you.

```
  <add name="mssql" 
       type="SubSonic.SqlDataProvider, SubSonic" 
       connectionStringName="mssql" 
       fixPluralClassNames="false" 
       generatedNamespace="ModeloDados" 
       regexMatchExpression="A-Za-z" 
       regexIgnoreCase="true" 
       removeUnderscores="false" 
       setPropertyDefaultsFromDatabase="true" 
       generateNullableProperties="true" 
       useExtendedProperties="true" 
       useUtc="true"/>
```

Comment: Which version of SubSonic are you using?

Comment: AFAIK, all MySQL tables have lowercase names, that's why you're getting such class names. Not sure if anything can be done about that, I don't think that you can get camel case out of MySQL with SubSonic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded one way..I used the "regexDictionaryReplace"  . This way work in mysql and mssql

```
  <add name="mysql" type="SubSonic.MySqlDataProvider, SubSonic"
             regexDictionaryReplace="Empresaendereco,EmpresaEndereco"
             fixDatabaseObjectCasing="true" connectionStringName="mysql"
             generateRelatedTablesAsProperties="true"
             fixPluralClassNames="false"
             generatedNamespace="ModeloDados"
             regexIgnoreCase="true"
             removeUnderscores="false"
             setPropertyDefaultsFromDatabase="true"
             generateNullableProperties="true"
             useExtendedProperties="true"
             useUtc="true" />
```

Thanks for all help!!!

Answer (score 0):

As Pawel pointed out MySQL on Windows and OS X uses only lowercase names for tables by default. There is a configuration option that you can use to change this behaviour. The following blog posting gives a brief overview:

[MySQL Case-sensitivity issues](http://www.cybersite.com.au/node/69)